# How to Debug JSNI method in GWT?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, jsni

I have a GWT application containing some JSNI methods. I am getting an exception from inside it. How can i debug the method in IDE or through Browser?

Comment: Refer https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/tgzTeAsn9bg

Comment: May be can try up to some extend by adding alert in between, and showing values needed to be verified. :)

Comment: @Piccaza that is the most possible weapon,if no clues left :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using 2.5.x, configure and run your project in [superdev mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode). Enable your chrome browser to use source maps. Finally you will be brought to the exception line in the debug console of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to @Thomas Broyer [HERE](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-web-toolkit/125bqsh306/how-can-i-find-jsni-code-in-firebug-or-chrome) (If you are using `Chrome`)

If you have an `exception` in `JSNI` code, you can ask `Chrome` to "stop on all
exceptions", and you'll see your `JSNI` code and will be able to step within
it. You can also try to "`pause script execution`".

P.S: I didn't try it. Just a clue to push you further.